# Warning about blocking item under version control (Xcode 4)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, xcode4, touchxml

I just added TouchXML to my project and it's telling me that:

> warning: Obstructing: /**/Classes/Creation is blocking item under version control

also, same thing for Tidy:

> warning: Obstructing: /**/Classes/Tidy is blocking item under version control

It's just a warning but it's very annoying; how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same issue but with my build folder. It was svn issue. after a clean up and update on build folder, I could delete the build folder and add set it to ignore.

Did you use TouchXML from a svn repository? You may check for any ".xxxx" folders.

// Update: I meant running svn cleanup and svn update commands.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "clean up and update on build folder"?